# How to serve folder in 'public' with express

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to serve the login page in my public folder in express, so far i have been unable to do so. I tried to work the path but I don't know why it does not work. What I want to have is that I can have more code in the callback but because of the way it is now I can do that, when I try to make the callback a full function it won't work either.

```
My folder structure
- root
  - server
    - server.js
  - public
    - login
      - index.html
```

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.listen(4000);
console.log('server started\n');


app.get('/', () => app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/login')));

// what i want to have 
app.get('/', () => {
  // serve file 
});
```

Comment: change the path to __dirname + '../public'

Comment: that sadly doesn't work, and without __dirname it doesn't either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render a HTML page form NodeJs API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967761/how-to-render-a-html-page-form-nodejs-api)

Comment: Request you to search little more before you ask question. See all these post are similar to yours and they answer your question very well. Post 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122677,  Post 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967362, Post 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208321, Post 4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52014410, Post 5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967761

Comment: @NAVIN none of the posts is related to this question ?! Also the duplicate you flagged has *nothing todo with this*. Please read questions more carefully before wasting everyones time

Comment: @JonasWilms question is regarding how to send an `html` page to browser using `express` framework in `nodejs`. If you knew then, we need to set a path and file format of out `html` which can be `ejs`, `jade` and `html`, we also need to mention where to look for all these `views` app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')). app.set('view engine', 'jade'). If our `html` page is using some sort of `JS` or `CSS` then these files are kept in `public` folder generally, that is link is also needed to be set app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))).

Comment: @NAVIN again: Those dupes make no sense, stop flagging irrelevant dupes

Comment: @JonasWilms If we are in need to send some data to these `html` page and from `html` page to our `node` application then we need `AJAX` calls and all these mentioned link tells us how to open a `html` page how to send data and receive data.

Answer (score 1):

You should mount the static file serving directly when the server starts, not after the first request arrives so this line:

```
app.get('/', () => app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/login')));
```

has to be:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public/login'));
```

You also have to go up one folder as the code is started in the `/server/` directory, which can be done with `/../`.

If you only want to server the index.html from public folder instead of all files in there, what you can do is

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname + '/../public/login'));
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i would like to have it as a callback function as well

<!-- language: lang-js -->
app.get('/', () => {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../public'));
})
<!-- end snippet -->

Comment: See... static routes are to serve static files not to listen to an endpoint request(which is not a resource). So if you want to liste to request to home path, what you should actually do is use res.sendFile or res.send with some data

Comment: static files request ends with a file name and extensions

Comment: Can you try the edit part? Remember you should have the correct __dirname path i.e. you should be running server.js file form server/ directory on command line

Comment: i will try it later, busy with other project